# How to output an error message in my JSF page, related to my httpresponse error

Tags: java, json, spring, jsf

I have this logic code (putting error to response):

```
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        Exception ex) {
    boolean maxSizeEx = true;
    if (ex instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
        logger.debug("tried to upload a file that exceeded capacity", ex);
    } else {
        logger.warn("caught unexpected exception", ex);
        maxSizeEx = false;
    }

    final boolean fMaxSizeEx = maxSizeEx;
    View view = new View() {
        public void render(Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (fMaxSizeEx) {
                data.put("error", "Limit size exceeded");
            } else {
                data.put("error", "internal error");
            }
            JsonApiController.mapToJsonAndOutput(response.getOutputStream(), data);
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
    return new ModelAndView(view);
}
```

and i want after that, to output the an error message in the view (my jsf page).

How can i do that in my jsf page ?

Here is the code of mapToJsonAndOutput method :

```
protected static void mapToJsonAndOutput(OutputStream out, Map<String, String> data) throws IOException {
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warn("You should not call mapToJsonAndOutput if there is no data");
        return;
    }
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    JsonGenerator g = f.createJsonGenerator(out, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    g.writeStartObject();
    for (Entry<String, String> e : data.entrySet()) {
        g.writeStringField(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    g.writeEndObject();
    g.flush();
    DevisPdfResourceController.close(out);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT :

```
if (fMaxSizeEx) {
            data.put("error", "Limit size exceeded");
        } else {
            data.put("error", "internal error");
        }
        JsonApiController.mapToJsonAndOutput(response.getOutputStream(), data)
```

The code data.put("error", "Limit size exceeded") seems not working, as i want to add error message to my response.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the simplest method in your case, but there's a JSF tag called `<h:messages>` which can display FacesContext message with 4 levels of severity.

See documentation : http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_messages.html

Here's how it works in a simple case :

View (.jsf) :

```
 <h:messages />
```

Controller (.java) :

```
 FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.YOUR_SEVERITY, "your description", "your message");
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
```